# beamer: Deactivate Overlay Specifications For Printouts

Tags: beamer, overlays

- Sometimes I use **overlay specifications** in `beamer` to control the order of appearance of specific elements.
- When I print out the presentation -- which is for my job needed sometimes -- then this generates often too much paper and is inconvenient for the people who get the printout.
- Is there a way/command to deactivate all **overlay specifications**?
- In `article mode` there are no overlays I think -- but I do not know how to use this here.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title 1}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title 2}

Text 1 \pause Text 2 \pause Text 3

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce handouts, use the `handout` mode:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title 1}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title 2}

Text 1 \pause Text 2 \pause Text 3

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Stupid me. Thanks! I need another 6 min before I can accept it. I have never used this mode before (just article).